# Average Time over a period of time in a SQL Query

Tags: sql, time, average, min

Hello how would i be able to get the AVG of the Minimum time across records?

Meaning, I have these records:

```
Id   Date    Time    Amount
1    7/1/14  9:00am  5.00
2    7/1/14  8:45am  6.00
3    7/1/14  9:30am  7.00
4    7/2/14  8:30am  4.50
5    7/2/14  9:15am  5.50
6    7/2/14  7:45am  4.75
```

now what i need is to get MIN of each day... so in this case it would be record 2, and 6.
but i want to some how average those times... meaning 8:45am and 7:45am ...

I want to know what is the average time first sale occurs over a time period.  Not sure how to average out the time. So to say, over a given period, generally first sale occurs around say 8:20 am (estimating)

tx very much for any assitance

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: What data type is used to store Time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the average, convert the time to seconds, compute the average and convert it back to a time.

```
SELECT Id, Date, SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(sec))
FROM (SELECT Id, Date, MIN(TIME_TO_SEC(Time)) AS sec
      FROM YOUR_TABLE
      GROUP BY Id, Date) AS TABLE1
GROUP BY Id, Date;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! i see what is needed, bring down to sec from day offset, then avg, then redisplay!  i am using access so actually i needed to do this something a little different.

Answer (score 2):

You can try somthing like this:-

```
SELECT Id, Date, AVG(Time)
FROM (SELECT Id, Date, MIN(Time) AS Time
      FROM YOUR_TABLE
      GROUP BY Id, Date) AS TABLE1
GROUP BY Id, Date;
```

This might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Format(( AVG(Table1.daTime) /86400),"hh:nn:ss") AS AvgTimeOfFirstTransaction
FROM (SELECT  date, (MIN(Time) *86400)  AS daTime
       FROM transactions
       WHERE (  (transactions.date)>=#7/1/2014# And (transactions.date)<#7/3/2014#) 
       GROUP BY transactions.date
)  AS TABLE1
```

Comment: This is what i'd actually need for access.   ahh but i just noticed that the sec * and / is not needed, what was truely missing for my use was just the formatting back to time from both the solutions.   Tx to both of you.